# Can Django channels receive 30fps video recording from a React Client ? or should I switch another library

Tags: django, websocket, django-channels

I am building a room monitoring app, and I was thinking of sending data using WebSockets and Django channels, but I am not sure if it's a good approach or if Websockets can send/handle 30fps video/image data to the server.

Comment: That depends on the size of the images. You should check the amount of data send per second, and check if the server (and network) can handle that.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I am receiving all of the data, but the problem is when I try to save the received images IO takes a lot of time. so say I'm receiving 15 images per second I am having a hard time saving all of the images.

Comment: you need to save all the images? Usually a webcam is not saved (or at least not indefinitely), since that would result in *gigantic* amounts of memory. A video also does *not* store the individual images, it saves one image, and then the *difference* between the previous one, since that takes less disk space.